# Jenkins parameterized build plugin doesn't pass to grandchild job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I use Parameterized Build plugin to trigger a train of 4 jobs.  Job 1 is set to "Trigger Parameterized Build on Other Project".  It calls job B and sets one parameter from a property file and one is set as predefined.

Job B has the two input parameters defined as String parameters, and the job finds both parameters and it runs fine.  Job B is set to "Trigger Parameterized Build on Other Project", and it calls job C.  Job C is parameterized to receive the same two parameters.

However, Job C never gets any parameters. In Job B I've tried passing the Current Build Parameters, I've tried setting Predefined Parameters (of type var1=${var1}, and even setting myTestVar=hello), but no parameters are ever found in Job C.

Job A is a maven build, Job B is freestyle, C is Maven again, and D is freestyle (if I ever get there).

I'm using Jenkins 1.623 and Parameterized Build Plugin 2.27.

I'm at a loss here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I recommend the following steps to troubleshoot this problem:

1. In a previously finished build in Job C, check `Parameters` to see if parameters did be passed in by Job B. If those parameters are not there, then you may want to check the parameterized build trigger configuration in Job B to see if it's correctly configured.
2. Try to print the parameters in a shell script using `echo` in the downstream job (e.g. Job C) to see if you can see the parameter in the console log. For example, `echo $foo`.
3. If you use Groovy script, make sure to use `System.getenv()` to get environment variables. For example, `def foo = System.getenv()["foo"]`.

Comment: Agh, I was in a groovy script instead of a shell script.  When I used a shell script with echo "Test: $testVar" it worked!